# Version Control with Structured Text files (*.ST, *.POE,*.bak)

Tags: version-control, structured-text, industrial

I would like to do version control with my structured text project (I use infoteam openpcs) for industrial applications. The problem is that each time I modify an *.ST file, I get changes also in *.POE and *.bak corresponding files. Is there any nice way to do version control of this type of files?. For me, it is very annoying to follow version changes, because each time I modify  onlye one *.ST file, I get the same change also in *.POE and *.bak. The thing is that I also would like to link this to redmine or TortoiseSVN and only see and/or recover the changes in the *.ST files. Is it possible?.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited by which version control tool to use, you can opt for Git. It provides a way to ignore certain file extensions (to be more exact, ignore any files matching various patterns specified by the user)

This page has a nice explanation on this feature - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore

Comment: I have already try it in the past, it kind of works but sometimes gitignore does not work properly as it detects changes in ignored files despite there have not been changed. Is there any other way?.

Comment: I've never had issues with gitignore. Sometimes you need to make some effort to correctly define the  ignore expressions. One common example is casing - if you ignore *.bak it would still track .BAK files